# App Engine dev_appserver.py with WebPack return 404 from Google Storage Local API

Tags: google-app-engine, webpack

I'm developing an app using Google App Engine Standard Environment with Python and frontend with Webpack. The application store photos in Google Storage and display them. When I deploy the app to App Engine everything works fine.

When I try to run the local dev_appserver.py and Webpack I get the exception bellow when trying to read from Google Storage API when accessing the app via Webpack DevServer port (3001 in my case). If build the Webpack static output and do the exact same request with dev_appserver.py port (8080) I get the photo back.

```
[appengine] ERROR    2017-08-26 20:19:18,786 photo_storage.py:31] Fail to read photo file
[appengine] Traceback (most recent call last):
[appengine]   File "c:\myapp\server\api\photo_storage.py", line 20, in read_photo_from_storage
[appengine]     file_stat = gcs.stat(filename)
[appengine]   File "c:\myapp\server\lib\cloudstorage\cloudstorage_api.py", line 151, in stat
[appengine]     body=content)
[appengine]   File "c:\myapp\server\lib\cloudstorage\errors.py", line 132, in check_status
[appengine]     raise NotFoundError(msg)
[appengine] NotFoundError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 404.
[appengine] Path: '/app_default_bucket/pics/185804764220139124118/395ebb68_main.png'.
[appengine] Request headers: None.
[appengine] Response headers: {'date': 'Sat, 26 Aug 2017 20:19:18 GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'content-security-policy': "default-src 'self'", 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-powered-by': 'Express', 'content-length': '211'}.
[appengine] Body: ''.
[appengine] Extra info: None.
```

This is the code that reads and write the files:

```
import logging
import os
import logging
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import app_identity

import cloudstorage as gcs

from models import Photo

def read_photo_from_storage(photo, label, response):
    bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                                 app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())

    filename = format_photo_file_name(bucket_name, photo.created_by_user_id, photo.crc32c, label)

    try:
        file_stat = gcs.stat(filename)
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = file_stat.content_type
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private, max-age=31536000' # cache for upto 1 year
        response.headers['ETag'] = file_stat.etag
        response.write(gcs_file.read())
        gcs_file.close()

    except gcs.NotFoundError:
        logging.exception("Fail to read photo file")
        response.status = 404
        response.write('photo file not found')

def write_photo_to_storage(user_id, checksum, label, file_type, image_content):
    bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                                 app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())

    filename = format_photo_file_name(bucket_name, user_id, checksum, label)

    write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                        'w',
                        content_type=file_type,
                        options={'x-goog-meta-crc32c': "{0:x}".format(checksum)},
                        retry_params=write_retry_params)
    gcs_file.write(image_content)
    gcs_file.close()

def format_photo_file_name(bucket_name, user_id, checksum, label):
    return urllib.quote("/{0}/pics/{1}/{2:x}_{3}.png".format(bucket_name, user_id, checksum, label))
```